# PDF First Page doesn't show in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, pdf, uiimage, nsurl

I have to show PDF First Page in `UITableViewCell's` `ImageView`.

My PDF Documents are located in document directory of app.

Here is my code in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSURL* url =[self.arrayOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIImage *cellImage = [self buildThumbnailImage:MyGetPDFDocumentRef(url.absoluteString)];

cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
```

And Here is buildThumbnailImage Method.

```
- (UIImage *)buildThumbnailImage:(CGPDFDocumentRef)pdfDocument
{
    BOOL hasRetinaDisplay = FALSE;  // by default
    CGFloat pixelsPerPoint = 1.0;  // by default (pixelsPerPoint is just the "scale" property of the screen)

    if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)])  // the "scale" property is only present in iOS 4.0 and later
    {
        // we are running iOS 4.0 or later, so we may be on a Retina display;  we need to check further...
        if ((pixelsPerPoint = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]) == 1.0)
            hasRetinaDisplay = FALSE;
        else
            hasRetinaDisplay = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        // we are NOT running iOS 4.0 or later, so we can be sure that we are NOT on a Retina display
        pixelsPerPoint = 1.0;
        hasRetinaDisplay = FALSE;
    }

    size_t imageWidth = 320;  // width of thumbnail in points
    size_t imageHeight = 460;  // height of thumbnail in points

    if (hasRetinaDisplay)
    {
        imageWidth *= pixelsPerPoint;
        imageHeight *= pixelsPerPoint;
    }

    size_t bytesPerPixel = 4;  // RGBA
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * imageWidth;

    void *bitmapData = malloc(imageWidth * imageHeight * bytesPerPixel);

    // in the event that we were unable to mallocate the heap memory for the bitmap,
    // we just abort and preemptively return nil:
    if (bitmapData == NULL)
        return nil;

    // remember to zero the buffer before handing it off to the bitmap context:
    bzero(bitmapData, imageWidth * imageHeight * bytesPerPixel);

    CGContextRef theContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, imageWidth, imageHeight, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow,
                                                    CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    //CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDocument = MyGetPDFDocumentRef();  // NOTE: you will need to modify this line to supply the CGPDFDocumentRef for your file here...
    CGPDFPageRef pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDocument, 1);  // get the first page for your thumbnail

    CGAffineTransform shrinkingTransform =
    CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(pdfPage, kCGPDFMediaBox, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), 0, YES);

    CGContextConcatCTM(theContext, shrinkingTransform);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(theContext, pdfPage);  // draw the pdfPage into the bitmap context
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfDocument);

    //
    // create the CGImageRef (and thence the UIImage) from the context (with its bitmap of the pdf page):
    //
    CGImageRef theCGImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(theContext);
    free(CGBitmapContextGetData(theContext));  // this frees the bitmapData we malloc'ed earlier
    CGContextRelease(theContext);

    UIImage *theUIImage;

    // CAUTION: the method imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation: only exists on iOS 4.0 or later!!!
    if ([UIImage respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:)])
    {
        theUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:theCGImageRef scale:pixelsPerPoint orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    }
    else
    {
        theUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:theCGImageRef];
    }

    CFRelease(theCGImageRef);
    return theUIImage;
}


CGPDFDocumentRef MyGetPDFDocumentRef(NSString *inputPDFFile)
{
    //NSString *inputPDFFile = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];

    const char *inputPDFFileAsCString = [inputPDFFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"expecting pdf file to exist at this pathname: \"%s\"", inputPDFFileAsCString);

    CFStringRef path = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, inputPDFFileAsCString, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);
    CFRelease (path);

    CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);
    CFRelease(url);

    if (CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document) == 0)
    {
        printf("Warning: No pages in pdf file \"%s\" or pdf file does not exist at this path\n", inputPDFFileAsCString);
        return NULL;
    }

    return document;
}
```

And Here is how i load pdf file list from document directory.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)loadBookFromDocumentDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[paths objectAtIndex:0]];

    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray *files = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDirectory]
                            includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLContentModificationDateKey]
                                               options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles

                                                 error:&error];

    NSArray* sortArray = [files sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                          ^(NSURL *file1, NSURL *file2)
                          {
                              NSDate *file1Date;
                              [file1 getResourceValue:&file1Date forKey:NSURLContentModificationDateKey error:nil];

                              NSDate *file2Date;
                              [file2 getResourceValue:&file2Date forKey:NSURLContentModificationDateKey error:nil];

                              // Ascending:
                              //return [file1Date compare: file2Date];
                              // Descending:
                              return [file2Date compare: file1Date];
                          }];

    NSMutableArray *sortedContents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sortArray];
    return sortedContents;
}
```

When i run my app , it doesn't show anything at Cell ImageView and showing this message.

```
file:///Users/MacUser/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/08BE9071-6251-44ED-A8E0-55CD478380FC/Documents/CGPDFDocument.pdf" or pdf file does not exist at this path
```

I am sure i have that pdf and even showing PDF Name in `TableView`.

Where am i wroning?

Comment: Looks like your problem is in your "`MyGetPDFDocumentRef`" function.  Show the code for that.

Comment: i added my code. please check it.

Comment: Right before you return from your MyGetPDFDocumentRef, print out how many pages the function sees.  That is:  "`NSLog(@"number of pages in document is %d", CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document));`".  Tell me if the number looks valid to you.

Comment: It's all right if i tested with mainBundle PDF File. But not with document directory pdf file.

Comment: well that isn't right, is it?  maybe that PDF file isn't ending up in your compiled app like you thought it was.

Comment: What do you mean? I tested with alot of PDF file and all are the same. How can i solve it?

Comment: You need to either copy your PDF file into your documents directory so that function can find it, or you need to change that "`MyGetPDFDocumentRef`" function so it's reading the PDF file straight out of the main bundle if that's where you want to hide it.

Comment: could you please provide some codes?

Comment: okay.. I'll do that but only if you show me how you create & populate your "`self.arrayOfBooks`" property.

Comment: yes. i added my code that load pdf lists from document directory. Please help me.

Comment: And in ViewDidLoad , it's simply load to NSMutableArray . self.arrayOfBooks = [self loadBookFromDocumentDirectory];

Comment: How did the PDF files get into the Documents directory to begin with?  Can you show or tell me how you did that?

Comment: I manually added with iTunes to document directory.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  I think I understand what's going on here.

You've "added your PDF files via iTunes".  I have NO idea how that is supposed to actually work.

But it's clear to me that the PDF files in your simulator folder are zero bytes in size.

The code you have right now should work, you just need to get valid PDF files into there to start with.

In Terminal, you can open that folder using the command

```
open ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/08BE9071-6251-44ED-A8E0-55CD478380FC/Documents
```

And when it opens in the Macintosh Finder, you'll see that all the PDF files in there are zero bytes in size.  Manually copy in your correct PDF files and your app should begin to magically work in the simulator.

Now, for production code, you need to write code to REALLY copy the PDF files into the documents folder.  Where do the PDF files come from originally?  Do you download them or are they built into the app somewhere?

Comment: I have already tested like you said. It doesn't work too. My PDF file that located that directory have correct MB.

Comment: I'm out of ideas here, Sabo.

Comment: Yes. thanks you very much you helped me that much. :) I am still trying to solve it.